# C# Unhandled Exception 'SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created'

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a small image-proccessing script in C#, and to do so I want to open an imagefile but even though I solved all errors, it gives me an 'Unhandled Exception' when I try to run the script. I tried moving the Application.Run(form1) to a seperate box because I thought it might try to initialize the SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault at the same time as 'form1', but that didn't change the issue

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{

static class Program
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Start(); 

    }
    public static Form1 form1 = new Form1();

    public static void Start()   // <-- must be marked public!
    {
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
}
}
```

and the code for form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile.Filter = "Image Files 
    (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp";
        if (openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)


        {
            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(openfile.FileName);
            imgbefore.Image = bit;
        }

    }

    private void imgbefore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        }
}
}
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: The *static* form1 object is the trouble-maker.  It does something naughty in its InitializeComponent() method that forces the native window to be created too early.  Something you can debug by overriding OnHandleCreated() and setting a breakpoint on it.  But probably not easily fix, even though you should.  Consider to instead create the object with a new expression in Start() and assign the static variable there.

Comment: This is a standard WinForms application. You only need `Application.Run(new Form1());` *after*  `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

This field initializer runs before any code in its containing class, including `Main()`.

You can only create the `new Form1()` after calling `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` (later in `Main()` or in a separate function).

Comment: Thank you! I put 'Form1 form1 = new Form1();' within the 'public static void start(){}' and that worked!

Comment: @TjeerdBakker If `@Slaks`'s solution worked for you then you may want to mark his response as an `Answer` so it can help other's, as well. Or if you think his response needs more clarification (like the one you described in your comment above) you may want to write your own response (referencing his response) and marking yours as an `Answer`.