# Run time Error when Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); is set

Tags: c#, office-interop

Trying to convert from a `Console` app to a `Winform` app. The following `Winform` code compiles fine, but at runtime I'm getting the following error. I went through various solutions of similar errors online, but was still a bit confused. Maybe, someone here can help for my following specific code:

NOTE: It's probably not relevant for the question of this post. But just in case: I'm referencing `micaut 1.0 Type Library` in my `VS2017` project that is needed for the code below.

**Error** [on Winform]:

> > SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.

**Code from Console app**:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using micautLib;

namespace MathInputPanel
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            MathInputControl ctrl = new MathInputControlClass();
            ctrl.EnableExtendedButtons(true);
            ctrl.Show();
            ctrl.Close += () => Application.ExitThread();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**An attempt to convert the above code to Winform app** [that gives the error]:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using micautLib;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); //error occurs here

    MathInputControl ctrl = new MathInputControl();

    ctrl.EnableExtendedButtons(true);
    ctrl.Show();
    ctrl.Close += () => Application.ExitThread();
    Application.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can only call that function before you create the first form.

Move that to `Main()` (if it isn't already there).

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). But since it's a `Winform` app where `Program.cs` already has `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` set. I did not have to move that line - instead just removed from my `button1_Click(…)` event above. You may want to mention that in your response (as it will help other). And I'll make your response as an `Answer`. Please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234046/c-sharp-unhandled-exception-setcompatibletextrenderingdefault-must-be-called-be/51234065#comment98970943_51234065) to regarding your similar response.

Comment: @nam: Clarified